# How to uninstall program without rebooting

Tags: c#

I have written a program to automatically uninstall a number of programs, using the ManagementObject in C#. It is working properly, except some programs automatically reboot the computer, and that defeats the purpose of my program. Is there any way that I can make it wait until everything is done uninstalling to reboot?

Here is the method that actually uninstalls the programs:

```
static void UninstallProduct(string path)
{
  ManagementObject product = new ManagementObject(path);

  if ((product != null) && (product.Path.ClassName == "Win32_Product"))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(
      "Uninstalling: "
      + product.GetPropertyValue("Name")
      + "...");

    object result = product.InvokeMethod("Uninstall", null);
    Console.WriteLine(
      "The Uninstall method result is {0}",
      result.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ManagementObject class, so I'm not writing this as an actual answer. Having worked with Windows Installer, I would suggest that you see if there's a flag that tells the object not to let the installer reboot the system and if there's a flag that you can look for in the return value that tells you that the install requires a reboot for completion. That's how Windows Installer works. Then once all of the programs have been uninstalled, if any needed a reboot, you can then force the system to reboot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try invoking the MSI (installer package) with the `REMOVE=ALL` and `REBOOT=ReallySuppress` options.

If the product uses a custom installer instead of using MSI, it may not have an option to skip reboot.  In such cases, I would contact the developers and point out that rebooting the computer without the administrator's consent likely constitutes a denial of service attack: interference with operation of computing equipment and willfully obstructing or delaying electronic communications, which are state and federal crimes.  If you are "helping them avoid liability" instead of beating them with the law and threat of prosecution, you may get the desired change in behavior (at least in future versions).

Comment: Is there any way you can show me an example invoking the MSI installer package? This seems like what I need to do, because there is no parameters for the uninstall method of a win32 product (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393941(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Landon: There's a `MSIInstallProduct` function which looks easy to use.  Your difficulty will be getting from the WMI objects to the MSI file path, in part because not every installed application uses MSI.

Comment: @LandonHammond: Try using the install or configure method instead, which does take options?  `REMOVE=ALL REBOOT=R` should cause it to uninstall even when the install method is used.

Answer (score 1):

See [.NET won't invoke method with command line args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152422/net-wont-invoke-method-with-command-line-args/20152956?noredirect=1#20152956) to understand why REBOOT=ReallySuppress may not be passed to the MSI uninstaller when you think it is. What has worked for me to force no rebooting during uninstallation is to kill all processes of the application that you wish to uninstall before you invoke the MSI uninstall method. Of course, that workaround is not foolproof and depends on the program that is being uninstalled.