# .NET won't invoke method with command line args?

Tags: c#, .net, uninstallation, restart, apimonitor

I am trying to uninstall programs in C# with the `REBOOT=ReallySuppress` command line argument, but a Windows process monitor (API Monitor by Rohitab) shows that my desired command line args are not actually being passed to msiexec.exe. Is there a flaw in my code?

```
public static List<ManagementObject> programs;       

public void Uninstall(int index)
{
    object[] args = {"REBOOT=ReallySuppress", "REMOVE=ALL"};
    programs[index].InvokeMethod("Uninstall", args);
}

...
```

The list of programs is initialized elsewhere in the code and is working properly. API Monitor shows that the msiexec.exe process was started with the following parameters:

`"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\\msiexec.exe" /i "C:\Users\Joel Denning\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\jre1.7.0_45.msi" /qn METHOD=joff`

which does not have the `REBOOT=ReallySuppress` or `REMOVE=ALL` arguments that I passed in.

Comment: Can you clarify why your code sample is defining and inititializing `args`? You said the issue is with command line args but they aren't being used in your code snippet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlaying Type is Win32_Product.
The Method uninstall of this class has no arguments.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393941(v=vs.85).aspx

So your code seems syntactically ok.

See [How to uninstall program without rebooting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537012/how-to-uninstall-program-without-rebooting)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this one was frustrating me. In my case I was able to force no rebooting by killing all running processes of the application that I was uninstalling. Once I did that, there was no need to pass args to the msi uninstaller because MSI only forced a reboot when there were running processes.